# paste same column from multiple files into one

Tags: awk

I have around 50 tab-delimited files of which I want to print column $7 to a new file. All files have the same amount of columns and the same amount of lines. In the output the columns from the different files should be pasted next to each other, seperated by tab.

I was thinking to use a combination of 'ls', 'xargs' and 'awk'. So ls to find all the file I want, then awk for printing the 7th column and create output.txt

```
ls /folder/*_name.txt | awk '{print $7}' xargs {} > output.txt
```

My main issue is the use of xargs and how to print all $7 in different columns in the output file

Comment: Maybe you could just use "cut -f 7 /folder/*_name.txt > output.txt"

Comment: With two files you can do `paste <(awk '{print $7}' a1) <(awk '{print $7}' a2)`, but I guess for 50 you need another approach.

Comment: @swstephe this prints all the values of all $7 below each other in one column, which is not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then with awk you could use

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR == 1 { ++file } { col[FNR, file] = $7 } END { for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) { line = col[i, 1]; for(j = 2; j <= file; ++j) { line = line "\t" col[i, j] }; print line } }' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

The code is

```
FNR == 1 { ++file }                 # in the first line of a file, increase
                                    # the file counter, so file is the number
                                    # of the file we're processing
{                         
  col[FNR, file] = $7               # remember the 7th column from all lines
}                                   # by line and file number

END {                               # at the end:
  for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) {       # walk through the lines,
    line = col[i, 1]                # paste together the columns in that line
    for(j = 2; j <= file; ++j) {    # from each file
      line = line "\t" col[i, j]
    }
    print line                      # and print the result.
  }
}
```

EDIT: Tweaked to assemble the lines on the fly rather than at the end, this could be shortened to

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR == 1 && FNR != NR { sep = "\t" } { line[FNR] = line[FNR] sep $7 } END { for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) { print line[i] } }'
```

That is

```
FNR == 1 && FNR != NR {   # in the first line, but not in the first file
  sep = "\t"              # set the separator to a tab (in the first it's empty)
}
{                         # assemble the line on the fly
  line[FNR] = line[FNR] sep $7
}
END {                     # and in the end, print the lines.
  for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) {
    print line[i]
  }
}
```

Tethering yourself to gawk, this could be further shortened to

```
awk -F '\t' '{ line[FNR] = line[FNR] sep $7 } ENDFILE { sep = "\t" } END { for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) { print line[i] } }'
```

...but `ENDFILE` is not known to other awk implementations such as mawk, so you may prefer to avoid it.

Comment: I see 'file1 file2 file3 file4' at the end of your command. I don't want to type all the paths to the files. That's why I was trying to use ls & xargs ...

Comment: You can just put `$(ls foo)` there. Or just `/folder/*_name.txt`, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't pretty but you could use Python to accomplish this VERY easily.  I wrote this in 5 min and tested it on three files that had equal columns and rows and it worked

```
import csv, os

def getData(fileDir, newFile, COLUMN):
    COLUMN = COLUMN - 1
    newFile = os.path.join(fileDir,newFile)

    #gets all filepaths for all your files in a directory
    filePaths = []
    for file in os.listdir(fileDir):
        filePaths.append(os.path.join(fileDir,file))
    originalData = []
    for f in filePaths:
        file = []
        with open(f, 'rb') as d:
            reader = csv.reader(d, delimiter='\t')
            #header = (reader.next())[COLUMN] #if you have a header in your csv file uncomment this line so it skips it
            for row in reader:
                file.append(row[COLUMN])
        originalData.append(file)

    #gets a count of how many rows are in your file
    rows = len(originalData[0])

    #creates a new list from the old list and it is now structured like below
    #new list = [[File1_Col7_Row1, File2_Col7_Row1, File3_Col7_Row1],[File1_Col7_Row2, File2_Col7_Row2, File3_Col7_Row2]]
    newData = []
    for i in range(rows):
        r = []
        for item in originalData:
            row = item[i]
            r.append(row)
        newData.append(r)

    #writes the new data to a new file
    with open(newFile, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
        for row in newData:
            writer.writerow(row)




if __name__ == "__main__":      
    #dir where ONLY the tab files reside
    fileDir = "C:\\TabFiles"
    #new file name, it will be dumped in the dir where the other files reside
    newFile = 'newTabFile.txt'
    # the column you want to grab
    columnNum = 7

    getData(fileDir, newFile, columnNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Python to create 10 files:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    fn='file'+str(i)+'.tsv'
    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        for line in range(1,4):
            f.write('\t'.join('{}, line: {}, col: {}'.format(fn, line, col) for col in range(1,10)))
            f.write('\n')
```

Which creates 10 files of this type:

```
file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 1  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 2  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 3  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 4  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 5  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 6  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 8  file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 9
file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 1  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 2  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 3  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 4  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 5  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 6  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 8  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 9
file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 1  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 2  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 3  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 4  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 5  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 6  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 8  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 9
...
file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 1  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 2  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 3  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 4  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 5  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 6  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 8  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 9
file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 1  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 2  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 3  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 4  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 5  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 6  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 8  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 9
file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 1  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 2  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 3  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 4  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 5  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 6  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 8  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 9
```

---

Now that you have those example files (and this is the answer) just use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f 7 *.tsv
file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file2.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file2.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file2.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file3.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file3.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file3.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file4.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file4.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file4.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file5.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file5.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file5.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file6.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file6.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file6.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file7.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file7.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file7.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file8.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file8.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file8.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 7
file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 7
file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
```

Then entab those results using `tr`:

```
$ cut -f 7 *.tsv | tr '\n' '\t'
file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file2.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file2.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file2.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file3.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file3.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file3.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file4.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file4.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file4.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file5.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file5.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file5.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file6.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file6.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file6.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file7.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file7.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file7.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file8.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file8.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file8.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
```

Or `paste`:

```
$ cut -f 7 *.tsv | paste -s -d '\t' - 
file1.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file1.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file2.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file2.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file2.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file3.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file3.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file3.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file4.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file4.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file4.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file5.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file5.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file5.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file6.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file6.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file6.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file7.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file7.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file7.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file8.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file8.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file8.tsv, line: 3, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 1, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 2, col: 7  file9.tsv, line: 3, col: 7
```